# Internet Explorer Ajax call, cached response issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this javascript function that I use in a *waiting page* to check if an exporting process in my web app is running or is finished:

```
function waitForExport(token) {
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : 'export/status',
        data : {
            token : token
        },
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'running') {
                $('#waitContent').append('<span>RUNNING</span>');
                setTimeout("waitForExport('" + token + "')", 5000);
            }
            if (data.status == 'done') {
                $('#waitContent').append('<div>DONE</div>');
                location.href = "export/results";
            }
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.

Using Internet Explorer 7/8 the process appears always running because, except the first time, it doesn't make any other server request (I verified using Eclipse debugger). It seems like it caches the first server response and then never hits the server anymore...

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
cache: false
```

in your `$.ajax()` options object.

What this does is append a `_=[TIMESTAMP]` to the end of the URL (without the `[ ]`). This makes the browser think it's always a completely different request because a different querystring is being used in the request.

Comment: no problem! i noticed this too when i was testing AJAX on internet explorer. it was a pain to figure out, but now i know to always set cache: false unless i know i don't care about cacheability

Comment: woooooo! glad i could help :)